Webflow Page Load animations start too late
I have some interactions directly in the hero sections of multiple pages, which start on page load. My problem is that all of them start too late. The page loads and only after a second or so after it finished loading, the animation starts (instead of directly after page load or even better as it says in the trigger name "While page is loading" (which it doesn't do at all)). All of my animations start with a "Set as initial state" and then without a delay they all do something, so I don't think it has something to do with the animations themselves.
As I can't attach a screenshot of one of the animations due to copyright policies of my company, I'll just explain one of the interactions as an example:
While page is loading → Start an animation:
[Set as initial value] Move X: 0%
[0.00s, 0 delay and 1s duration] Move X: 50%
This still does not start while page is loading or at least directly after page load, but as mentioned about a second after page is fully loaded.
Does anyone have a solution to this?

You are going to need to show some code for anyone to guess why its loading slowly.  Do you have graphics loading too?  Can you compress the images or convert them to their proper size manually to reduce their size and increase loading?  Is there a response buffer setting for webflow that allows the page to display before its done loading (so your animation gets loaded quicker?)  Its most likely that your page takes a second to download and thus only then does it start animating.
